# how to get exact 3 months ago date and time from today's date and current time using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get data from database which is saved from past 3 months for that i have current date and time but how to calculate 3 months ego date and time, SO that i can pass these 2 dates in the query and get the data which was saved between these dates

Comment: have you tried `var prevDate = currentDate.AddMonths(-3);`

Comment: Define "3 months ago". Do you mean 90 days ago? Or the same day in month 3 months ago? What should be the result for May 29th?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the [`AddMonths` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx):

```
DateTime ago = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
```

Comment: +1 The best answer because, if you don't assign the value returned by the `AddMonths` method, it's useless.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `-3` as parameter in [`AddMonths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) method

```
DateTime dtPreviousDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
```

[DateTime.AddMonths Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx)

> A number of months. The months parameter can be negative or positive.

Answer (score 0):

[`AddMonths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) can be negative.

```
DataTable tblResult = new DataTable();
string sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.TableName WHERE Date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endData";
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    // asuming that your startdate is three months ago and your enddate is now
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", DateTime.Now);
    da.Fill(tblResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime olddate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month - 3, now.Day);

Comment: You might want to test your code on 1st of January again and then rethink your solution. 29th/30th/31st of May are also good days for another test.